# Laravel login - redirect only if success

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel login controller, but I call it from a vuejs dropdown in my page, not from a specific page.

If the authentification fails, it is still redirecting to /mypage. I would like a redirection only if the login works. Is it possible? (I don't want to redirect back either, I would like the page not to refresh at all).

In my LoginController

```
 protected $redirectTo = '/mypage';
```

If I remove it, it redirects to /vuelogin

(for info) vuelogin is the route I created for login so that I can add a middleware. this is the one I am calling when the user clicks "login"

```
Route::post('vuelogin', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->middleware('loginnewpassword');
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you’re not calling api for login and after that just handle the route.

Comment: I don't understand your answer... I am calling Auth\LoginController@login for login. How would you suggest to handle it?

Comment: It will be better if you share whole functions code here